Git Search in All Branches in Intellij 2024
I upgraded fron Intellij 2022 to Intellij 2024,
I'm using GitToolBox plugin to view and manage git repositories
Before upgrade I had an option to select All and find all commits in all branches
But now I don't have such option as below

How to search in All Branches in New Intellij 2024 ?
You can see in JetBrains page that All is an option


There's a change in behavior,
You now need to leave value blank or if branch already chosen, click on X sign to unselect it and view all branches

Also the same for User/Date fields
